# VSCode Python Debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to debug a simple python file.    The test.py file just contains the text print("hello").
When I select Run->Start Debugging  I get a modal dialog with the following text:

h.toLowerCase is not a function

When I open the config I see:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "simple"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the results of navigating to Help->About->Copy.

> Version: 1.51.0 (user setup) Commit:
> fcac248b077b55bae4ba5bab613fd6e9156c2f0c Date:
> 2020-11-05T18:18:23.642Z Electron: 9.3.3 Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
> Node.js: 12.14.1 V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0 OS: Windows_NT x64
> 10.0.19042

If I start a command window, I can type python or pip, so those things are in my path.

```
Python --version generates
3.9.0
```

VS Code extensions shows that I have the following extensions installed.

> Python v2020.10.332292344
> Python for VSCode 0.2.3

If I right click in the python file and click run python in console.  It works ok.  I see the text "Hello" in the console.

Comment: Have you executed the command: `Python: Select Interpreter`

Comment: Can you break down how I'd do that?  In the lower left corner of VSC, it says Python 3.9.0 64 bit error 0 warning 0 Python Current File (t2)

Comment: Select language mode in lower right is saying python.

Comment: Why would a javascript function be getting called by the python interpreter

Comment: I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode and Python to no effect on this box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this out.  This article was helpful.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

There's an optional key called console.  Possible values: internalConsole, externalTerminal or the default integratedTerminal.  Temporarily, set this key to externalTerminal.  Run the F5 or Run->Start Debug again.  You'll get an error message that looks like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "...\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "...\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "...\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 242, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "...\python\.vscode\launch.json", line 2
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The error message points out that it got stuck on the Intellisense comment.  As a developer, comments are typically a good thing.  But this is clearly a problem in the templated launch.json file.  If you remove the comments and set the console key to internalConsole, things seem to work.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "simple",
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: my `launch.json` has comments and I don't have problems debugging python files, I get this error/exception if I press F5 when `launch.json` is my current file

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "python",
    "pythonPath":"${config.python.pythonPath}", 
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "console": "none",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "RedirectOutput"
    ],
    "env": {"name":"value"}
}
```

Comment: I wish I could share a screenshot.  I added this json to the launch.json file as my configuration.  The python path variable is underlined and debugOptions is underlined.